# GCC inline assembler using memory references

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to write an inline assembly instruction that will load a variable with the contents of a register by using a pointer to that variable instead of a direct reference.

The code using a direct reference works fine and it looks like this:

```
int x;
int *y = &x;
int z = 1;

__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %%edx, %0;"::"r"(z):);
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %0, %%edx;":"=r" (x)::); 
printf("\n%x\n", x);
```

disasm:

```
0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp  
0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp                                          
0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp                                         
0x0000000000400535 <+8>:     lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax                                   
0x0000000000400539 <+12>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)                                    
0x000000000040053d <+16>:    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)                                    
0x0000000000400544 <+23>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax                                    
0x0000000000400547 <+26>:    mov    %edx,%eax                                          
0x0000000000400549 <+28>:    mov    %eax,%edx                                          
0x000000000040054b <+30>:    mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)                                   
0x000000000040054e <+33>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax                                   
0x0000000000400551 <+36>:    mov    %eax,%esi                                          
0x0000000000400553 <+38>:    mov    $0x4005f4,%edi                                     
0x0000000000400558 <+43>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                                          
0x000000000040055d <+48>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>                              
0x0000000000400562 <+53>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                                          
0x0000000000400567 <+58>:    leaveq       
0x0000000000400568 <+59>:    retq
```

and it outputs 1 as expected

The pointer version looks like this:

```
int x;
int *y = &x;
int z = 1;

__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %%edx, %0;"::"r"(z):);
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov (%0), %%edx;":"+r" (y)::);
//or
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %[mem], %%edx":[mem] "=m" (y)::);
printf("\n%x\n", x);
```

disasm:

```
0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000000400535 <+8>:     lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000000400539 <+12>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x000000000040053d <+16>:    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
0x0000000000400544 <+23>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400547 <+26>:    mov    %edx,%eax
0x0000000000400549 <+28>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edx
0x000000000040054c <+31>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax
0x000000000040054f <+34>:    mov    %eax,%esi
0x0000000000400551 <+36>:    mov    $0x4005f4,%edi
0x0000000000400556 <+41>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040055b <+46>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
0x0000000000400560 <+51>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400565 <+56>:    leaveq 
0x0000000000400566 <+57>:    retq
```

This prints a non-deterministic integer every time (i.e bb524b90 15979050). When run in gdb it prints the same integer (ffffe2f0) every time, which doesn't change based on the value of z. Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

Comment: `mov %%edx, %0` So... you are moving the (undefined) contents of edx to the (read only) variable %0?  By default gcc uses att syntax, which is (usually) the reverse of intel syntax.

Comment: That first assembly should not work either. If it prints 1, it must be some accident.

Comment: You have UB if you don't specify `"memory"` in the clobber list.

Comment: To me it almost seems you may not realize that in AT&T syntax that source and destination are reversed. Source is the first operand and destination is the second (Intel syntax is opposite)

Comment: Depends on which case you are referring to @o11c : `__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %[mem], %%edx":[mem] "=m" (y)::);`wouldn't require it but `__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov (%0), %%edx;":"+r" (y)::);` would (There are other issues though in those two inline assembly templates though. There is also a dereference missing on `"=m" (y)`. Think he was going for `"=m" (*y)`

Comment: Thanks Micheal and @o11c! Your suggestions worked for both lines. I don't see any difference when adjusting for intel/att syntax though.

Comment: It really is unclear what you are trying to do. are you trying to get the value in _EDX_ and palce it into a memory location or the other way around?

Comment: @Dan: I think you need to read some inline asm tutorials / guides.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for some links.  For example, you're writing to `%0` after telling the compiler it's an input operand, or reading an output-only (`"=r"`) operand.  So nothing you're doing makes any sense.  Neither does hoping the compiler doesn't touch `%edx` between two separate `__asm__` statements.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm just testing out the functionality of the gcc inline assembly function, placing a value into `edx` and then placing the value of `edx` into a different variable, both with direct reference and by passing a pointer, no real application.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm pretty sure the __volatile__ flag will make sure the instructions are placed in their respective positions in code, so the `edx` register shouldn't be touched between instructions. Also, for the line you're referencing, I am getting output from the reg, not input, notice the argument positioning `"mov %0, %%edx;":"=r" (x)::`

Comment: @DanPesce : `__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov $3, %%edx\n\tmov %%edx, %[mem]":[mem] "=m" (*y)::"edx");` would be an example using your method of moving  a value (3 in this case) into _EDX_ and then moving it to a memory address. I'm not suggesting this is ideal, but i think it is close to what you are looking for with your thinking.

Comment: @DanPesce : `volatile` won't guarantee that inline assembly will appear in the order they are present in the code if the inline assembly statements have no dependencies in common. It may well be the compiler will generate them in that order, but that shouldn't be assumed. If you want to guarantee order of successive inline `asm` statements you can place more than one instruction in the template similar to what I did with the example above. i separate each instruction with `\n\t`. You could also use a `;` to separate instructions. `\n\t` makes assembly output cleaner if you use GCC's `-S`option

Comment: `volatile` does guarantee execution order of ask statements. What it does not guarantee is the absence of intervening code, textual order and memory address order.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting output from the reg, not input, notice the argument positioning `"mov %0, %%edx;":"=r" (x)::`

You're confused about input/output terminology.

An output operand is an output *from the `asm` statement*, *into* a register chosen by the compiler (for the `"=r"` case).

When you use `"=m"`, the compiler will make `%0` a memory operand.

Or if you used `"=a"`, `%0` would be `%eax`, and the compiler would assume that the value of the C variable `x` is now in `%eax`.

---

In AT&T syntax, the destination operand is the last operand.  I think you do know this, but I think you have input/output backwards.